# How to copy entire folder from local machine to Amazon Sagemaker or vice-versa?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-run, docker-cp

I want to copy a folders/files from my local machine (MAC) to the docker container in Amazon Sagemaker .

I tried using scp commands to copy from local to sagemaker,
for folder

`scp -r -i <key> <local address> ec2-user@<ip>.compute-1.amazonws.com:/<address>`

and then logged in to sagemaker and used
`docker cp  :/workspace/

I want to move a folder or file directly from my local machine (MAC) to amazon sagemaker docker container using only 1 terminal command.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you want to copy something into the docker container? That is usually done using the dockerfile.

Comment: Yes I want to copy something in docker container from my local machine , but that docker container is in amazon sagemaker

Comment: Also according to `https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/` the docker cp`commands copies only from local filesystem to the docker container. So I don't think it's taking an URL. Maybe try scp from local to Amazon server and docker cp on the server.

Comment: the commands you shared are for using docker directly, but when I do `docker cp` that doesn't work, may be because I want to copy it to sagemaker thats where docker container is

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant: copy first to the Amazon server and do it "locally" there.

Comment: edited question...